# Google Analytics - Track multiple subdirectories

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website where users can create subdirectories and files, and I need to be able to track each subdirectory separately as it's created.

For example: if my site is www.domain.com

```
User 1 creates www.domain.com/user1/index.html
User 2 creates www.domain.com/user2/index.html
```

I need to be able to automatically track subdirectories user1 and user2. I can't manually go into GA admin panel and add a segment/filter each time a new subdirectory is created to track it. I also need to be able to display this data back to the users.

Is this possible with Google Analytics?

Comment: In what way do you need to display this to the users - do you want to give them access to the google account or do you want to programmatically pull the data from the account and display it on a webpage ?

Comment: I would like to programmatically pull the data from the account and display it on a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do this very easily.

1) Programatically added the google analytics code to each new page the user creates. This automatically tracks traffic to individual subdirectories.

2) Used oocharts.js to display the data individually, by passing in a filter like so.

```
var timeline1 = new oo.Timeline("12345678", "30d");
timeline1.addMetric("ga:visits", "Visits");
timeline1.query.setFilter('ga:pagePath=~/user1/'); 
timeline1.draw('chart1');

var timeline2 = new oo.Timeline("12345678", "30d");
timeline2.addMetric("ga:visits", "Visits");
timeline2.query.setFilter('ga:pagePath=~/user2/'); 
timeline2.draw('chart2');
```